# Youtube Video, wordpress

Tags: time, youtube, video-streaming, scheduled-tasks

I wants To Show my video according to time slot in wordpress.As Example i scheduled the multiple video according to their different timezone as 11:00 AM, 12:00 AM,Video Is Only Showing When The Scheduled Time is arrived according to their different perspective timezone.
So Please Help Is There Any Plugin or any idea to do this.
Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin should do the trick. https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-to-show-or-hide-content/

Just wrap the video in the shortcode like so...

```
[time-restrict on="18:00:00" off="20:00:00"]

This video will show between 6 and 8PM

[/time-restrict]
```

Comment: Is There Any Paid Plugin Because On Basic Plugin Having Limted Feature.
And Also Working With Different Timezone.

Comment: Use it in combination with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-clients-time-zone/